# Existe alguna manera de limitar el consumo de recursos de hardware para un contenedor de docker desde un fichero docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Estuve intentando con el ejemplo de debajo, pero al parecer solo es compatible cuando se ejecuta docker en modo swarm.

```
deploy:
  resources:
    limits:
      cpus: '0.1'
      memory: 100M
    reservations:
      cpus: '0.1'
      memory: 100M
```

Comment: [Sí](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#resources)

Comment: muchas gracias amigo. la prisa no me dejó percatarme de la nota